# Passing table name as an argument in PostGIS function

Tags: postgis, postgresql, function, pg-tileserv

How can I pass my table name as an argument of a function?

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE
 FUNCTION public.countries_name1(
        z integer, x integer , y integer,
        name_prefix text default 'B' )
 RETURNS bytea
 AS $$
 -- Convert tile coordinates to a bounding box 
 WITH
 bounds AS (
 SELECT ST_TileEnvelope(z, x, y) AS geom,
   (CASE 
    when z >= 16 then 5
    when z = 15 then 50
    when z = 14 then 100
    when z = 13 then 150
    when z = 12 then 200
    when z <= 11 then 300
    --when z <= 10 then 500
    --when z = 9 then 700
    --when z = 8 then 800
    --when z = 7 then 900
    --when z <= 6 then 1000
     
    ELSE 1 END
   ) as simplify_tolerance
   
   
),
-- Convert raw geometry into MVT geometry
-- Pull just the name in addition to the geometry
-- Apply the name_prefix parameter to the WHERE clause
mvtgeom AS (
  SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform(ST_simplify(t.geom,simplify_tolerance), 3857), bounds.geom) AS geom,
    t.fclass,z,x,y
  FROM table_name t, bounds
  WHERE ST_Intersects(t.geom, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 25833))
  AND upper(t.fclass) LIKE (upper(name_prefix) || '%') AND z>=10
)
-- Serialize the result set into an MVT object
SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom, 'public.countries_name1') FROM mvtgeom;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
STABLE
     PARALLEL SAFE;
```

In this code I want to pass my table_name from function parameter.

Comment: This thread will help you understand what to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter

Comment: This isn't really a PostGIS issue as much as it is a PostgreSQL one, and therefore would be better researched in [dba.se] or [so].

Comment: I already tried from that but it did not work in my case. The function is removed from pg_tileserv from that method @TimothyDalton